# Google Maps API Search

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-maps, google-api

I am currently working on a Javascript program that uses the google maps API. 
What it needs to do:

1. Allow user to enter a location.
2. Once the user clicks the "find" button, it converts the user's entered location into longitude and latitude co-ords.
3. Then it runs an algorithm to calculate the distance between the users entered location and  20 hard coded lng and lat co-ordinates.
4. It will output the distance in KMs.
5. Then it will have to loop through and find the lowest distance and grab the lng and lat id so I know what location was the shortest distance.

I have manged to get steps 1 and 2 done but I can't find a way to store the index of a location ( a way to identify it ) and the lng and lat points so that I can loop through them and compare them to the location the user inputted. Nor can I figure out a way to find the shortest distance will all of the points to find closest lng and lat.

Any help would be appreciated,

THANKS!

Comment: Hi! Welcome to SO. Show us some code, so we can share a common starting point.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to adapt this answer for your purposes.

```
//forumla for calculating distances between points
var getDistance = function(p1, p2) {
  var rad = function(x) {return x*Math.PI/180;}
  var R = 6371; // earth's mean radius in km
  var dLat  = rad(p2.lat() - p1.lat());
  var dLong = rad(p2.lng() - p1.lng());

  var a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
          Math.cos(rad(p1.lat())) * Math.cos(rad(p2.lat())) * Math.sin(dLong/2) * Math.sin(dLong/2);
  var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));
  var d = R * c;

  return d.toFixed(3);
}

// LatLng object with your current coordinates
var yourLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(yourlat, yourlng);

// populate an array of hard coded LatLng objects 
var twentypoints = {};
twentypoints['hardcodedName1'] = new google.maps.LatLng(lat1, lng1);
twentypoints['hardcodedName2'] = new google.maps.LatLng(lat2, lng2);
twentypoints['hardcodedName3'] = new google.maps.LatLng(lat3, lng3);
  ...

// calculate the minimum distance
var closestLocName, minDist;
for (var hardcodedName in twentypoints) {
  tempMinDist = getDistance(twentypoints[hardcodedName], yourLocation));
  if (minDist === undefined || tempMinDist < minDist) {
    minDist = tempMinDist;
    closestLocName = hardcodedName;
  }
}

console.log('Closest location is called ' + closestLocName + '.');
console.log('Closest location is ' + minDist + 'km away.');
```